# Extracting point values from a raster using .csv files

Tags: r

My research is about determining forage quality parameters using random forest regression in R. I have the GPS values for 5 different farms(FINCA) as well as the data quality values of Patia. I'm calculating the vegetation indices of a mosaic imagery I have of Patia to input as predictor variables for the grassland forage quantity and quality random forest regression models. All files can be found here:

[DATASET](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1g-3UljKDj2brvJ_xmSiWddho9k3PP6vT?usp=sharing)

The problem I'm facing is in extracting raster values to point. My dataset is of PlanetScope imagery which has 4 bands: BGR and NIR. When I try to extract the points for the bands or the indices using the datosPatia.csv file, I get NA values for all 65 locations:

```
###########################################

setwd('D:/uni/project MSc/Patia/mosaic')
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#open your ndvi raster 
r<- raster("NDVI.tif")  
r

#read the csv file for sample points
pts<- read.csv('datosPatia.csv')
coordinates(pts)= ~ Longitude+ Latitude

#extract point values
ndvi= extract(r, pts)
ndvi 

combinePointValue1=cbind(pts,ndvi)

write.table(combinePointValue1,file='combinedPointValue1.csv', 
            append=FALSE, sep= ",", row.names = FALSE, 
            col.names=TRUE)

########################################################
```

This didn't work so I used the kml files from the FINCA folders instead of the csv files:

```
#########################################

F1 <- st_read("FINCA01/FINCA01.kml")
plot(F1)

#open your raster
r<- raster("NDVI.tif")  
r

#For example:
ndvi= extract(r, F1)
ndvi 

combinePointValue1=cbind(F1,ndvi)

write.table(combinePointValue1,file='combinedPointValue1.csv', 
            append=FALSE, sep= ",", row.names = FALSE, 
            col.names=TRUE)

########################################################
```

The extract function gave this error but it produced a csv file with the point values.

```
Warning messages:
1: In proj4string(x) : CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
2: In .local(x, y, ...) :
  Transforming SpatialPoints to the CRS of the Raster
```

Can anyone tell me how I can put all these combinedpointvalues .csv files together as one file or if there is any other non repetitive way to get the values from all farms in one code because right now I'm writing the same code over and over for different farms.

Regarding the datosPatia. csv file, is it giving NA values Is it something to do with the structure of the .csv file and the column headers?

Comment: I just downloaded your data and there's no `NDVI.tif`. Can you upload that so we can try your code?

Comment: Do your points and rasters all have the same coordinate system? This will need to be the case. Please verify.

Comment: The NDVI raster has the following CRS:  crs        : +proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
The shapefile has geographic CRS: WGS 84

Comment: @Spacedman I added the data.

Comment: That is the problem--all of your spatial data need to have the same coordinate system. I would recommend using the UTM projected coordinate system.

Comment: @Aaron what about the csv file i wanted to use originally? I want the data of the datosPatia csv file. The CRS is a shapefile related issue, isn't it?

Comment: The coordinates in the CSV file need to be the same spatial reference as your raster data you want to sample. My guess is that your CSV coords are geographic and your raster data are projected.

Comment: I changed the CRS for the csv data file to crs : +proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs, same as the raster, but the result is still the same. NA values for the NDVI.

Comment: How did you "change the CRS"? Just overwrite the old WGS84 with the other one or actually reproject it (e.g. using spTransform() or whatever sf uses instead)?